# Class and ID difference

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand how the ID &  class works in the below class,

For example:-     `#switcher .button` will select all elements with id = switcher but im wondering how .button selects "button selected" class as well..

html

```
<div id="switcher">
        <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
        <div class="button selected" id="switcher-normal">Normal</div>
        <div class="button" id="switcher-narrow">Narrow Column</div>
        <div class="button" id="switcher-large">Large Print</div>
 </div>
```

id

```
#switcher {
  float: right;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: .9em;
}
#switcher h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
#switcher .button {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #888;
  border-left: 3px solid #888;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #444;
  border-right: 3px solid #444;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a **specific** question? Right now it just looks like you need to read about the basics of CSS.

Comment: please use `google` for basic question :http://www.google.com/search?q=difference+id+and+class&oq=diference+id+and+class&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.14299j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: you can have several classes in your html,just they must to be separated by a space, so, button and selected are two class for one element and .button works fine... where is your problem now?

Comment: @oGeez & Radian, this looks like a perfectly valid question to me. Easy to answer, but are beginners not allowed to ask questions anymore?

Comment: There is an entire internet full of information on CSS, why answer what has already been answered? Props go to Dan Green, that's a very nice answer - But there's nothing there that the OP couldn't have found out with a little research, which never hurt anyone.

Comment: But it does allow for beginners to get a clear and concise understanding of how HTML classes and IDs work.  Even if it isn't really what SO is meant for, I still think it can help people to move past that initial confusion which stops many people from starting the process of learning web development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes allow you to select multiple elements, or multiple classes.

IDs allow you to refer to a single, specific element.

Classes should be separated by a space, you can only have one ID

For the HTML:

```
<div id="switcher">
    <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
    <div class="button selected" id="switcher-normal">Normal</div>
    <div class="button" id="switcher-narrow">Narrow Column</div>
    <div class="button" id="switcher-large">Large Print</div>
</div>
```

With CSS you could select

`.button` to select all items with `button` as a class

or

`.selected` to select all items with `selected` as a class

or

`#switcher .selected` for all items with `selected` as a class inside the the element with `switcher` as its ID.

or

`.button.selected` for all items with both `button` and `selected` as a class

or

`#switcher .button.selected` for all items with both `button` and `selected` as a class and is within the element with the ID `switcher`

Comment: Correct answer, but two small remarks:

- It **is** possible to use more than one ID, if you're talking about the CSS selector. `#main-page #switcher` is a perfectly valid selector where #switcher is only addressed if it is contained within a #main-page element.

- I don't know if the OP noticed, but the key difference between `#switcher .selected` and `.button.selected` is the placement of the space character. With a space character, we are looking at two elements, one containing the other, while without space we're talking about one element that contains both classes.

Answer (score 1):

A single class attribute of a DOM will match any CSS class selector that is the same as a substring of the class atribute separated by white spaces. For example, a DOM with `class="button selected"` will match a CSS selector `.button` or `.selected`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `#switcher .button` will not select the class `selected`. If you want to make that happen, you need to use `#switcher .button:first-child` or `#switcher .button.selected` if you want to make only the first child which is having a `selected` class or the `` `#switcher .button `` with selected to select the values from this `#switcher .button` descendent selector.

Answer (score 0):

The core difference between a class and a id is that a *id is always unique*, where you can use as many of the same classes as you want.

---

You say:

> For example:- #switcher .button will select **all elements** with id =
>   switcher

This is not true. It will actually select all elements with the class "button", where the parent element has the ID "switcher".

You ask:

> wondering how .button selects "button selected" class as well..

Well you should note that `class="button selected"` defines TWO classes. The space makes place for a new class. So this element can be defined with `.button` AND `.selected`.

Your element has the class `.button` that is why it is selected.

---

I suggest to read some basic tutorials on the web about css selectors, ids and classes.

Hope this helped you!